# Selenium web tests on saucelabs is slow from Australia

Tags: selenium, saucelabs

We are an Australia based company developing a web app and using SauceLabs to do Selenium E2E testing. The problem is the test is slow on SauceLabs (6 mins from Australian server vs 30mins+ on SauceLabs).

We have API servers in both Australia and the US, so the API request time shouldn't be a problem.

My questions are:

1. Are Saucelabs' VMs all located in the US?
2. Does Selenium send test scripts line by line?

If both guesses are true, then sending selenium scripts from an Australian Jenkins server to SauceLabs can take long.

If not, what could possibly be the reason and, what's a good solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SauceLabs since 2014 and wrote [Saucery2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saucery2) and [Saucery3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saucery3).  I continue to maintain them.  I live in Melbourne.

I was surprised to find that their documentation was lacking in 2014 and it is still thus.  While I don't have hard data on the locations of their servers I suspect they are a smaller company in SOMA that their online presence would portray and thus it would not surprise me that their server are still in the US.  I am sure this is not something that will remain the case, IF my suspicion is correct.  It might not be.

They still remain the best cross browser offering in my opinion out there.

I would be very surprised if Selenium sent test scripts line by line.